# How to display records in a second data table based on the selected row in the first data table via end users side

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf

I dont want to create any tables dynamically. I have 2 Data table (Admin LTE data tables) in the frontend side.

Table 1: nadPatientTable (Displays patient record)
Table 2: nadPatientTreatmentsTable (Displays patient treatment records)

Relationship between these 2 tables are 1 to many. 1 patient can have many treatments. Relationship between these 2 tables is with an attribute column called pid, that is the id value of nadPatientTable is used as foreign key to refer pid of nadPatientTreatmentsTable.

Objective:
when the end user select any part of the row from nad_patient table. Based on the row that is selected. The code should fetch the id value of nad_patient table and using this id the code should  display all the treatment records asscoiated with this patient in nad_patient_tmt table referencing pid. In other words i want to dynamically display treatment records based on the selected patient.

Doubts:

1. How to implement this type of logic. Is there any correct video tutorial or reference material to implement this type of specifications?
2. Is there a concept in Jquery/Ajax that perform the above functionality. If so please specify this concept.

Current Code snippets using thymeleaf

nadPatientTable html code:

```
       <div class="card-body">
                <table id="nadPatientTable" class="table table-bordered table">
                  <thead class="thead-custom">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Treatment</th>
                    <th>File No.</th>
                    <th>Military ID</th>
                    <th>Civil ID</th>
                    <th>Name(E)</th>
                    <th>Name(A)</th>
                    <th>Date of Birth</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Rank</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Nationality</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>  
                    <tr th:each="f:${nadpatientList}">  
                          <td><a th:href="@{/recPageRegistration/findById/(id=${f.id})}" id="editTreatmentButton" data-target="#editTreatmentModal">+Treatment</a></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.id}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.mid}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.civilid}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.name}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.nameA}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.dob}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.gender}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.rank}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.mobile}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.unit}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.nationality}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.stat}"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  
                </table>
              </div
```

nadPatientTable js code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#nadPatientTable").DataTable({
    "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
    //"buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
  }).buttons().container().appendTo('#nadPatientTable_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
  $('#example2').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "responsive": true,
  });
});
```

nadPatientTreatmentsTable html code:

```
<div class="card-body">
                <table id="nadPatientTreatmentsTable" class="table table-bordered table">
                  <thead class="thead-custom">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Treatment ID</th>
                    <th>Meal Plan ID</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>T.Energy</th>
                    <th>BMI</th>
                    <th>BF</th>
                    <th>BMR</th>
                    <th>IW</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="f:${nadpatientTmtList}">  
                          <td >
                              <a class="updatePatientTmtButton">
                                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp;<span th:text="${f.id}"></span>
                              </a>
                          </td>
                          <td th:text="${f.id}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.tplSdate}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.tplEdate}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.stat}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.ten}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.bmi}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.bf}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.bmr}"></td>
                          <td th:text="${f.iw}"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  
                </table>
              </div>
```

nadPatientTreatmentsTable js code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#nadPatientTreatmentsTable").DataTable({
    "responsive": true, "lengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false,
    //"buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
  }).buttons().container().appendTo('#nadPatientTreatmentsTable_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
  $('#example2').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "responsive": true,
  });
});
```